# TightVNC X11VNC Rendering Distortion

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution, tightvnc, x11vnc

My `x11vnc` Server Debian + `tightvnc` Client Windows render me the following image errors while typing:

[image]

I'll appreciate if anybody who has experienced this before with tightvnc + x11vnc, could please me lead me to a troubleshoot.